# Mysql: copy selected columns to another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to copy the data from `online_class:class_category` to `categories:uuid,title`

**Table: online_class**

| ... | category | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | category 1 | ... |
| ... | category 2 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

**Table: categories**

| uuid | title | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |

```sql
INSERT INTO `categories` (`uuid`, `title`) 
    SELECT 
        (SELECT UUID()) AS `uuid`,
        DISTINCT(`class_category`) AS `title`
    FROM `online_class`
```

Getting this error

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'DISTINCT(`class_category`) as `title`
    FROM `online_class`' at line 4
```

What's wrong in this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to do this.

```sql
INSERT INTO `categories` (`uuid`, `title`) 
    SELECT UUID(), `class_category` FROM `online_class`
    GROUP BY `class_category`
```

Comment: What is the reason for to use subselect? And you do not need to assign columns aliases in SELECT part of INSERT - it uses positional matching strictly. `... SELECT UUID(), class_category FROM ...`, rather than CREATE TABLE .. SELECT.

Comment: Apologies, you are right. It's just that I was hitting and running the code for quite a while and pasted which executed. I'll improve the answer. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO categories(`uuid`, `title`) 
SELECT uuid, DISTINCT(class_category) 
FROM online_class
```

another example

```
INSERT INTO order_data(`item_name`, `item_id`) 
SELECT item_name, item_id 
FROM item_order
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function.